# How to flatten polymorphic lists with Moshi deserialization

Tags: android, moshi

I'm trying to flatten the following Json

```
[
  {
    "type": 1,
    "field": ""
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "field": "",
    "other_field": ""
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "field": "",
    "list_field": [
      {
        "type": 4,
        "some_field": ""
      },
      {
        "type": 4,
        "some_field": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

what I'd like to obtain is the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "type": 1,
    "field": ""
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "field": "",
    "other_field": ""
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "field": ""
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "some_field": ""
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "some_field": ""
  }
]
```

Since all the items inherit from the same parent class I tried both PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory and a custom JsonAdapter.Factory but without success.

Is there a way to do that in Moshi?

Comment: gson custom type adapter can help with this, moshi has some limit

Comment: I used gson type adapters in the past but since I need this in a project that uses Moshi I'd like to find a way using it